# How can you plot `geom_point()` with `facet_wrap()` using per-group row number as x?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-point

Is there a way to plot `geom_point()` so that it implicitly uses the row number as `x` in a facet? Just like `plot(y)` but also for multiple facets.

The following fails with `Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x`:

```r
df = data.frame(y = rnorm(60), group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 20))

ggplot(df, aes(y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

Naturally, you can do it using something like the following, but it is quite cumbersome.

```r
df = df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number())

ggplot(df, aes(x = row, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

Comment: Could be helpful for you this? `ggplot(df, aes(x=seq(y),y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + facet_wrap(~group)`

Comment: @Duck Thanks, that solved my problem. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: Great I will do now!

Comment: If you have time and if you consider the answer was helpful you could accept it :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=seq(y),y = y))+geom_point() + facet_wrap(~group)
```

In that way you can avoid the creation of an index variable as you mentioned!!!